# gwt celltable not working type class constructor undefined

Tags: java, gwt

I'm using gwt sdk 2.6.0. My problem is that when I only use two fields being "name" and "address" everything works ok. But when I add a third field "año" my code fails. Compiler says "constructor contact is undefined".

```
public class Tablila extends VerticalPanel {
    private static class Contact {
        private final String name;
        private final String address;
        private final String año;

        public Contact(String nombre, String address, String año) {
            this.name = nombre;
            this.address = address;
            this.año = año;
        }
    }

    private static List<Contact> CONTACTS = Arrays.asList(new Contact("ruben",
        "av.lomas", "15"), new Contact("jos", "av.juliet", "35"));

    public Tablila() {
        setUp();
    }

    public void setUp() {
        CellTable<Contact> table = new CellTable<Contact>();

        TextColumn<Contact> nameColumn = new TextColumn<Contact>() {
            @Override
            public String getValue(Contact contact) {
                return contact.name;
            }
        };

        table.addColumn(nameColumn, "Name");

        TextColumn<Contact> addressColumn = new TextColumn<Contact>() {
            @Override
            public String getValue(Contact contact) {
                return contact.address;
            }
        };

        table.addColumn(addressColumn, "address");

        TextColumn<Contact> añoColumn = new TextColumn<Contact>() {
            @Override
            public String getValue(Contact contact) {
                return contact.año;
            }
        };

        table.addColumn(añoColumn, "Año");
        table.setRowCount(CONTACTS.size(), true);

        // Push the data into the widget.
        table.setRowData(0, CONTACTS);

        this.add(table);
        this.getElement().getStyle().setMargin(8, Unit.PX);
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems problem with special character above like `ñ`. what is this? are you doing copy paste code from somewhere? declare it manually.

Comment: Is your source file encoded in UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

This means you cannot construct your Contact object by passing three values to it.

I see that you have such constructor in the code that you pasted, but in this case you should get an error when passing 2 values.

I compiled your code, and there were no errors. Did you save the changes to your code?

Comment: In this case he would get an error message when passing two values, not three.

Comment: So where is the issue?

Comment: There are no issues here. This code compiles without any problems.

Comment: gwt converts my java code to javascript , i guess that in order to use more than two columns , it has to be specified in a different way.

Comment: I don't see any errors in JavaScript either, sorry.